# Html structure for text-image-text on one line

Tags: html

I dont know exactly what is the html tags structure I have to write for this:

[image]

This is my try:

```
<p class="servicio_recogida"><span class="servicio_recogida">Servicio de <span class="rojo">recogida</span><span>/</span><span class="rojo">entrega</span> gratis</span></p>
<img src="images/tfno_cabecera.png">
<p><span class="tfno">91 457 04 67 / 91 457 85 20</span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

how about this example (using html & css only):

(see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mDVg/) sample)

[image: jsfiddle result]

html:

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="center">
        <span class="text">Servicio de recogida/entrega gratis</span>
        <img src="your/src.jpg" />
        <span class="num">91 457 04 67 / 91 457 85 20</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.cont{width:100%;height:50px;background:orange url('your/bgimg.jpg') repeat-x;}
.cont .center{width:500px;margin:0 auto;position:relative;top:10px;text-align:center;color:#000;font-size:16px;}
.cont .center .text{display:inline-block;font-weight:bold;}
.cont .center img{display:inline-block;max-width:35px;max-height:35px;margin:0 10px;}
.cont .center .num{display:inline-block;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: thanks! I have just pasted what I tried in my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use.

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
   Text on <span style="color:#FF0000">the left</span>
   <img src="image.png" width="32px" height="32px" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
   Text on <strong>the right</strong>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7p57k/) code is here**

Answer (score 0):

NO No NO! You people are so not HTML5...*tut *tut... Anyways you need to do this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum... <img src="images/example.png"> Lorem Ipsum...</p>
```

Yup that simple just right in and don't tell me the formatting is wrong because I see it everywhere...